# Views - Test if field is visible via PHP

Tags: views, theming

I am developing a custom theme for a specific view. I need to iterate and render each row and field, How can i do that?

Some code:

```
foreach($view->rows as idx => $row)
{
    foreach($view->field as $name => $handler)
    {
        //I need to check if the field is hidden from
        //display here
        $view->render_field($name, idx);
    }
}
```

I am going through with the debugger and use `$handler` array options, but within that I could not find any field that is visible or not.

Can anybody help?

Comment: _"hidden from display"_ - you mean the option _"Exclude from display"_ is checked for the field in the view?

Comment: yes, that is the case!

Answer (score 1):

Data that you are looking for is located at `$field->handler->options['exclude']`. But it is tricky to get to.

When you mark the field as excluded, its data becomes inaccessible at the field's level in your View's template.

`$row` object also does not have any indication that the field was excluded via Views UI. `$row` contains only the value data from each field. You can confirm that by doing dsm($row); in your View template file (if you have devel module installed).

If you are overriding you View's template on the `"Row style output"` level, than the only object you can use to reach `options['exclude']` from already excluded fields is `$views`.

You could do something like this at the top of your .tpl file:

```
foreach ($view->field as $view_field)
    {
        //check if field is excluded
         if ($view_field->options['exclude'] == 1) {
             // field is exluded - do something
             print $view_field->field.' is excluded from this view'; // print name of excluded field 
             print $row->field_field_yourfieldname[0]['raw']['safe_value'];
        }
    }
```

so, if the field is excluded - it is going to be excluded in each row, according to that you can assign some markup or text to a variable and then print it anywhere down the template.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate the each row and field, you have to override the view template.
To override view template, go to the particular view.

On the right side, there is `Theme` field in the `Advance section`.

Click on the theme field, there is a various type of template to override.
Click on the `Row style output`. A popup will open. Copy the entire code and place the code in `template` directory of your theme and give it a name as there are suggested and then save it.

Now you can do any kind of changes for this particular view.

Comment: The code above is placed there. I forgot to mention this...